# How to keep consistent the behaviour of a record / record stop button in a custom cell in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a record button in a custom cell in a UITableView with two images - when you press the button it shows the image for 'stop' record and when you stop record it shows you the image for 'record'. However, when I press the record button the stop image changes on another row in the tableview and not in the button of the cell I have just pushed.

I have tried to make the behaviour of the button consistent by using a delegate protocol method to set up the custom cell. But this has not resolved the issue.

**Code for the custom cell (CreateStoryCell)** is as follows:

```
import UIKit


protocol createStoryCellDelegate {
func didRecord(sender: UIButton, storyItem: StoryItem)
}

class CreateStoryCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var storyCellBackground: UIView!


@IBOutlet weak var storyTextLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var record: UIButton!

var storyItem : StoryItem!
var delegate: createStoryCellDelegate?

func setStoryItem(storyPart: StoryItem) {
    storyItem = storyPart
    storyTextLabel.text = storyItem.text

}

@IBAction func recordTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    delegate?.didRecord(sender: sender, storyItem: storyItem)
}

}
```

The extension for the **setting up of the cell for tableView** is here:

```
extension CreateStoryViewController : UITableViewDataSource {


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "createStoryCell", for: indexPath) as! CreateStoryCell

        let storyItem = storyText?[indexPath.row]

        cell.setStoryItem(storyPart: storyItem!)        

        cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}


}
```

And the **didRecord method** is here:

```
extension CreateStoryViewController : createStoryCellDelegate {

func didRecord(sender: UIButton, storyItem: StoryItem) {

    if recordToggle == 1 {

        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "recordStop"), for: .normal)

      checkRecording(storyItem: storyItem)

      audioRecorder.record()

        recordToggle = 2


    } else {

        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "smallMicBtn"), for: .normal)

        audioRecorder.stop()

        recordToggle = 1


    }

}

}
```

Please also note that the above delegate method begins to work until I insert the record functionality i.e. as soon as I make active the 'audioRecorder.record()' and 'audioRecorder.stop() lines the button behaviour becomes inconsistent as described above.

Previous, I have tried to implement this by converting the position of the record button to an indexPath with the following:

```
//        let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.createStoryTableView)
//        let indexPath = self.createStoryTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
//        let storyItem = self.storyText?[indexPath?.row ?? 0]
```

But I got the same behaviour.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions on how to resolve. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend to introduce a new variable var isRecording = false in your StoryItem and change its value on start/ stop record button click and reload that particular cell.
In your cellForRowAt use this 
let storyItem = self.storyText?[indexPath?.row ?? 0]

let image = (storyItem. isRecording == true) ? (UIImage(named:"stopImage")) : (UIImage(named: "startImage"))

cell. record.setImage(image, for: .normal)

Comment: Thanks, this is the method that I used and it worked. Do you want to put it in the answers section?

Comment: Great it worked.
I'll post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to introduce a new variable 
`var isRecording = false` in your StoryItem and change its value on start/ stop record button click and reload that particular cell. 
In your cellForRowAt use this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let storyItem = self.storyText?[indexPath?.row ?? 0] 
 let image = (storyItem. isRecording == true) ? (UIImage(named:"stopImage")) : (UIImage(named: "startImage")) 
 cell.record.setImage(image, for: .normal) 
 return cell
}
```